# Why the numeric_limits Machine Epsilon does not satisfy the 1+e>1 condition?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, epsilon

If I'm not wrong the definition of the Machine Epsilon is the lowest number that satisfies the condition:

[image: 1+e>1]

I was trying to test this making use of the `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` but the value does not satisty this, if you try to get the prior float number with `std::nextafter`:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    float e = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
    float previous = std::nextafter(e, -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ((1.0f + previous) > 1.0f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This stills outputs `true` https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/841e19dafcf0bf6f.

After trying to get the number using `std::nextafter` I noticed that the proper Machine Epsilon should be:

```cpp
std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() / 2.0f, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
```

I tested it using this code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

bool verify(float e) {
    return ((1.0f + e) > 1.0f);
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<float>::digits);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::fixed;

    float epsilon = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();

    float last = epsilon;
    while (true) {
        last = std::nextafter(last, -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
        if ((1.0f + last) > 1.0f) {
            epsilon = last;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Does not satisfy condition
    std::cout << "last: " << verify(last) << " " << last << std::endl;
    // Satisfy condition
    std::cout << "epsilon: " << verify(epsilon) << " " << epsilon << std::endl;

    float half_epsilon = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() / 2.0f;
    float actual_epsilon = std::nextafter(half_epsilon, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
    // Same as 'last' at this point
    std::cout << "half_epsilon: " << verify(half_epsilon) << " " << half_epsilon << std::endl;
    // Same as 'epsilon' at this point
    std::cout << "actual_epsilon: " << verify(actual_epsilon) << " " << actual_epsilon << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
last: false 0.000000059604644775390625
epsilon: true 0.000000059604651880817983
half_epsilon: false 0.000000059604644775390625
actual_epsilon: true 0.000000059604651880817983
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c66a2144e80a91b

Am I missing somethig here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357415/machine-epsilon-precision-discrepancy asks why double and float epsilon are calculated to be the same and why that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I'm not wrong the definition of the Machine Epsilon is the lowest number that satisfies the condition: [`1 + epsilon > 1`]

Close, but you are wrong in the context of C++. (I believe your definition is correct in other, more academic contexts.) According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon), the machine epsilon is "the difference between `1.0` and the next value representable by the [specified] floating-point type". The machine epsilon does satisfy `1 + epsilon > 1`, but it need not be the *lowest* number that satisfies that. It is, though, the lowest number that satisfies that condition *under all rounding modes*.

Because the machine epsilon is so much smaller than `1.0`, there are plenty of representable values between the epsilon and `0.0`. (That's a basic goal of floating point representations.) When any of these is added to `1.0`, the result is not representable, so the result needs to be rounded. If the rounding mode is to the nearest representable value, then that sum will round to `1 + epsilon` whenever the small number is between `epsilon/2` and `3*epsilon/2`. On the other hand, if the rounding mode is always towards zero, then you get the result you were expecting.

Try adding `#include <cfenv>` and the following line to your code.

```
fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
```

This causes any sum strictly between `1.0` and `1 + epsilon` to round to `1.0`. You should now see the machine epsilon behaving as you expected.

*The other guaranteed rounding modes are towards -infinity and towards +infinity. See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round) for details.*